# Flutter break string in array and split it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving data in a string like this

```
IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION)FOR ONLY PARENTS ||||||||||ACCIDENTAL INJURIES=COVERED|||||MEDICAL EMERGENCIES=COVERED FROM OPD AND OPD REIMBURSEMENT BASIS
```

I want to show this in listview. And I need to break it by ||||| and split it by =

Mean in the list it will show like

```
 IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION)FOR ONLY PARENTS 
 ACCIDENTAL INJURIES : COVERED
 MEDICAL EMERGENCIES : COVERED FROM OPD AND OPD REIMBURSEMENT BASIS
```

The issue is how can I break it by |||? because sometimes the length of | is 5 sometimes 10 and so on. I just want whenever | is come it's just skip remaining | and just break it.

I am doing like this

```
  List wordings = wording.split('||||');
  print(wordings);
  List splited;
  wordings.forEach((element) {
    splited = element.split('=');

    var displayPolicy = {'name': splited[0], 'value': splited[1]};
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  });
```

It's working but the issue in this is its only break when |||| is four i want to skip this at any length

Edit

I am now doing like this

```
  String wording = data['records'][0]['policies'][0]['policywording'];
  List wordings = wording.split(RegExp(r"[|]+"));
  print(wordings);
  List splited;
  wordings.forEach((element) {
    splited = element.split('=');
    var displayPolicy = {'name': splited[0], 'value': splited[1]};
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  });
  print(displayData);
```

when I print wordings it's showing like this

```
[IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION), , ||ACCIDENTAL INJURIES=COVERED, |MEDICAL EMERGENCIES=COVERED FROM OPD]
```

It's not splitting and showing an error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above both answers are correct you need to add some condition because on your string all values don't have "=" sign so that's why its showing this error. You can handle it like this

```
List wordings = wording.split(RegExp(r'\|+'));
List splited;
wordings.forEach((element) {
  if (element.contains("=")) {
    splited = element.split('=');

    var displayPolicy = {'name': splited[0], 'value': splited[1]};
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  } else {
    var displayPolicy = {'name': element, 'value': ''};
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  }
});
```

if your data don't have "=" it will just add in "name" of `displayPolicy` and if its have "=" sign then they have both name and value. you can manage it by your pattern now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex

```
 wording.split(RegExp(r"[|]+"));
```

this site is a good place to learn
https://regexone.com/

Comment: Can you check my updated question i have try this but not working

Answer (score 1):

use regexp to split
`List wordings = wording.split(RegExp(r'\|+'));`

```
List wordings = wording.split(RegExp(r'\|+'));
print(wordings);
List splited;
wordings.forEach((element) {
  splited = element.split('=');
  var displayPolicy = {'name': splited[0], 'value': splited.length > 1 ? splited[1] : ''};
  displayData.add(displayPolicy);
});
print(displayData);
```

Comment: Can you check my updated question i have try this but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if you want

```
String text = "IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION)FOR ONLY PARENTS ||||||||||ACCIDENTAL INJURIES=COVERED|||||MEDICAL EMERGENCIES=COVERED FROM OPD AND OPD REIMBURSEMENT BASIS";
  List sentences = text.split('|');
  sentences.forEach((wordPart){
    if(wordPart != ""){
      // Here do your another split for the equals
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I would split it by '|' and store it in a list, parse the list and remove empty elements.

Answer (score -1):

Because the first element of your list **wording** ("IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION)FOR ONLY PARENTS") doesn't contain '=' , so now first element of your List **splited** is "IN-PATIENT AND DAYCARE TREATMENT (HOSPITALIZATION)FOR ONLY PARENTS" and there's no second element, that's why it's throwing a range error,, because there's no index 1, simply the length of **splited** is 1, and you're trying to access second element, that's not possible.

Make sure the length of the list **splited** is 2, and if it's not add an empty string for index 1;

check this example

```
 List wordings = wording.split('||||');
  print(wordings);
   List splited;
   wordings.forEach((element) {
   splited = element.split('=');
     if(splited.lenght <2){
       splited.add('n/a');
     }

    var displayPolicy = {'name': splited[0], 'value': splited[1]};
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
});
```